# Asp master page change content

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP and this question will be very basic.I searched the net for quite a while and I am starting to think that I'm trying to do something wrong.I have a very simple master page with 3 LinkButtons on the top and 3 child master pages for each button.So the whole idea of that master page is to change the child page(content place holder) dynamically or am I wrong.And if am not how do I switch between the child pages showed in the content section?

I would place the code but its simple as explained.

Comment: Your description sounds a lot like a [SPA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A master page is for defining controls and content that you want to remain across all pages using that master page, For instance a menu, header, footer etc. Rather than coding the menu for each individual page you can have 1 menu in a master page.

To switch between pages its quite simple, You create multiple child pages for the master page, Like Home, About, Contact, Etc

Add on click events to each button to redirect to those pages this can be done using html `<a>` links or in the code behind, code behind sample:

```
protected void Home_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String URL = "~/Default.aspx";
        Response.Redirect(URL, false);
    }

protected void About_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String URL = "~/About.aspx";
        Response.Redirect(URL, false);
    }
```

These are onclick events in the master files code behind, for the button controls on the master page. Sample of button code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Home" runat="server" OnClick="Home_Click" CausesValidation="false">Home</asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user `Response.Redirect();` to redirect it to your specific content page in the `OnClick` Event of your respective `LinkButtons`.